# Election: Moderator Term Length

Tags: discussion, election

How long is the term for moderator? Is it one year?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no specific term - it is until a moderator steps down or is removed.

[Should Community Moderators be "elected for life", or have terms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/984/should-community-moderators-be-elected-for-life-or-have-terms)

Answer (score 3):

There are no "terms" for moderators. Instead, they retain their position mostly indefinitely. This is subject to challenge if, say, the moderator wishes to step down (such as if they never had the time for it) or if things go south. Otherwise, they stick around all the time.

Answer (score 3):

Would we be interested in an unofficial community standard for that? Kind of a polite, "we go for six months at a time and then rotate it up among those interested?"

... Though our current crowd of pro tempore folk has been pretty awesome.

Comment: I think some type of boundry would be nice. I would support an [un]official term expiration. However a time limit may be arbitrary, so I asked (What is an appropriate boundary for the end of a moderator’s term?)[http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/551].